# How can i pass the id while editing in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to pass the id when only user edit the document .here is my html and component.ts

Html

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<form  [formGroup]="addTaskForm"  (ngSubmit)="save()" >
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select formControlName="name" placeholder="Element Name">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let element of Elements" [value]="element.name">
      {{ element.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select  formControlName="symbol"  placeholder="Element symbol">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let element of Elements" [value]="element.symbol">
      {{ element.symbol }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div mat-dialog-actions>

  <button type="button" mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
<button type="submit"  mat-button cdkFocusInitial>Add</button>



</div>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {
 Elements = ELEMENT_DATA; 
addTaskForm: FormGroup;
  symbol = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  name = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  id = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    if(data.element){
      console.log(data.element.name);
     this.name = data.element.name;
     this.symbol = data.element.symbol;
     this.id = data.element.id;
    }
     this.addTaskForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: this.name,
      symbol: this.symbol,
      id: this.id
    });
    }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
  save(Element) {

    console.log('working');
    console.log(this.addTaskForm.value);
  }
}
```

when user click add popup will open with two dropdowns and add a button that time I don't want id but when user click edit button popup window will open with particular row details that time if user click add button I should get the particular id , name, symbol in component

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-afnyip?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the **`id: this.id`** while you are adding

```
  this.addTaskForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: this.name,
      symbol: this.symbol,
      id: this.id
    });
```

also pass the id with your modal,

```
if(data.element){
 console.log(data.element.name);
 this.name = data.element.name;
 this.symbol = data.element.symbol;
 this.id = data.element.id;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-fqajwv?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)**